# Encrypt / Decrypt with Login and Usertype

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, encryption

I'm using Encrypt and Decrypt for Username/Password and save it on database, at the same time I use it with Usertype which user can login with their own panel.

On registration, Encrypt was working fine and save in database but when I try to login, the password that I put didn't work. I think the Decryption didn't work to call the password I put and I can't login to the interface.

I'm using System.Security.Cryptograph and System.IO.

Class File

```
class Cryptography
    {
        public static string Encrypt(string clearText)
        {
            string EncryptionKey = "dk&;=GZ>j6KSev,<dm>cZG's$maAiD";
            byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(clearText);
            using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
            {
                Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
                encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
                encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                        cs.Close();
                    }
                    clearText = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
                }
            }
            return clearText;
        }
        public static string Decrypt(string cipherText)
        {
            string EncryptionKey = "dk&;=GZ>j6KSev,<dm>cZG's$maAiD";
            cipherText = cipherText.Replace(" ", "+");
            byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
            using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
            {
                Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
                encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
                encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
                        cs.Close();
                    }
                    cipherText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray());
                }
            }
            return cipherText;
        }
    }
```

Login File

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Connection.Open();
            MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT RegistrationType FROM registration Where Username='" + tbUsername.Text + "' and Password='" + tbPassword.Text + "'", Connection);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count == 1)
            //if(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
            {
                switch (dt.Rows[0]["RegistrationType"] as string)
                {
                    case "Administrator":
                        {
                            this.Hide();
                            Dashboard.dbAdmin DashboardAdmin = new Dashboard.dbAdmin();
                            DashboardAdmin.Show();
                            break;
                        }

                    case "Staff":
                        {
                            this.Hide();
                            Dashboard.dbStaff DashboardStaff = new Dashboard.dbStaff();
                            DashboardStaff.Show();
                            break;
                        }

                    default:
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Please enter correct username and password or register a new account!", "Alert", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error); ;
                            break;
                        }
                }
            }
            Connection.Close();
        }
```

The result I got is nothing. I keep press login button and still didn't show anything. Since the password has been Encrypted, how can I Decrypt the password with the login code above?

Comment: It looks to me like you're just looking for the plain-text password entered by the user to found in its encrypted state on the database, so that is going to fail every time. To correct that problem you'd want to encrypt the password entered by the user and compare that to the encrypted version you have saved in your database. That just solves the logic problem tho, the real question is should you be using 2-way encryption for passwords in the first place and storing the keys right there? Strongly consider using/storing only a 1-way hash of the user's password and using those for authentication

Comment: Also, since you're not using sql parameters your login could be pretty easily bypassed with simple sql-injection. So please strongly consider parametrizing
 your query as well

Comment: To express the importance of parameters, if I typed `' or 1=1 --` into the username textbox, the query would become `SELECT RegistrationType FROM registration Where Username='' or 1=1` which would return at least one row with a RegistrationType, which would allow me to log in without even entering a valid username or password.

Comment: @soohoonigan thanks for the explanation. I will improve my code as your suggestion. Is there any references for me to look for 1-way has as you mention?

Comment: There is a nuget package called bcrypt.net core, it handles all the salt and hashing for you and can be used with a single line of code. Makes it very easy to implement hashing

Comment: Thanks for the nuget package. I'm using winform and will this package can be installed on my application? That all for my questions.

Comment: Yep, just open the nuget package manager in visual studio and search for bcrypt and install

Comment: Just create a hash of password and compare it to check if match. No need for decrypt password?

Comment: @soohoonigan i try using bcrypt. On registration, it's good. But since I have user type, I don't know where to put the code for decrypt and start with. Can you help me on this one?

Comment: @LeszekP that the problem I have right now. But as suggest from soohonigan, I try with BCrypt, but still I don't have any idea how can I put the decrypt code. Since I have user type, I didn't know where to start.

Answer (score 1):

As [soohoonigan said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56693889/encrypt-decrypt-with-login-and-usertype/56694038#comment99953174_56693889), you should encrypt the user password typed and compare it with the storaged password on database.

You don't need to decrypt it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes Don't decrypt password at screen level.
2. Use encrypted password from screen and database compare them.
3. If it is right login else give message.